# WPF: Why TOO SLOW to Get PrintDialog's .PrintableAreaWidth and .PrintableAreaHeight?

Tags: wpf, printing

I am experiencing an extremely wired WPF PrintDialog issue -- Windows XP64 + VS2010.

It is pretty unbelievable that it is very very slow to get PrintDialog's .PrintableAreaWidth or .PrintableAreaHeight property.

// see sample codes below - remember to include "using System.Windows.Controls"

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
double pw = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;    // set a break-point here, very slow, why???  
double ph = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;
```

Anyone has any idea regarding this? I appreciate any thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PrintableArea` refers to the actual Printer in use - your app has to contact the printer to get that info, and my guess is that's the reason why it's slow. It shouldn't be any faster in WinForms...

If you'd want to optimize, you could cache the printer name and it's defaults and use that instead of querying the printer each time.

Comment: Is sounds making some sense as my computer is a network Canon printer not a local one.

Comment: But, the thing is that I need to find a good place in the appliation to cache the printer and its settings. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this was the answer to your question please mark it so (checkmark on the left). Thanks.