# Printing from WPF too slow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and I need to print from it. I had previously posted a question about printing without needing to display a confirmation window and got a great answer that I have implemented like the following

```
var pq = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(pq);
var paginator = newPass.docMain.Document.DocumentPaginator;
writer.Write(paginator);
```

This code works just fine and simple - it basically just picks up the local printer que and sends the XPS document. However, it is relatively slow to print. I've tried to narrow down the possibilities and it looks like the greatest speed difference is between WinXP and Win7 machines. On XP it is slow, but acceptable, at about 2-3 seconds to print while on Win7 it can be upwards of 10 seconds and 15 seconds is not uncommon. Is there a reason why this code would have such a difference in speed? Also, I've noticed that there are a few questions on here about WPF print speeds - is there a reason why WPF printing in general is slow?

Comment: Can't speak to why it runs so slow on Windows 7, but have you considered putting the print operation in a thread or a `BackgroundWorker` so it doesn't block the UI?

Comment: The concern isn't so much as blocking the UI as much as it is about overall speed. In this case, I'm generating a ticket and need to issue tickets as quickly as possible and the person can't leave me until I hand them the ticket. So moving the UI along wouldn't help per se.

Comment: What's actually slow ? The time between writer.Write, the time it takes the document to appear, the actual printing time ?

Comment: Its the actual printing time that seems to be the slowest. I can see the document appear in the printer que rather quickly. But the printer sits and thinks for a good 10 seconds before printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps one or more of these links will be useful in solving this issue:

http://www.bradymoritz.com/wpf-printing-performance-and-pdf

http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/willemm/archive/2008/11/03/WPF-Speed-tips.aspx

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/printing-is-very-very-slow-in-windows-7/477b5aba-a93d-4c5e-ac1f-329fed6459f3

[WPF: Why TOO SLOW to Get PrintDialog's .PrintableAreaWidth and .PrintableAreaHeight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187395/wpf-why-too-slow-to-get-printdialogs-printableareawidth-and-printableareaheig)

Answer (score 1):

Most printing speed problems that I have seen were related to the printer driver. The task of the printer driver is to translate graphical instructions (coming from WPF in this case) to instructions that the printer understands, the so-called PDL (typically PCL or PostScript). Often, the PDL supports only a subset of the graphical capabilities and consequently complex instructions result in huge PDL jobs. Transparancy flattening being a notorious one.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your issue on my own development machine, a Windows 7 (64-bit) PC.  With an almost trivial, 1-page `FixedDocument`, printing seems to be almost instantaneous (well under 1 second).  The printing happened to a standard corporate network-printer, as well as to a local PDF writer (DoPDF), and both performed well.  Something definitely seems to be different on your side, and I think you are prematurely assuming that it's a WPF issue.

In order to narrow down your issue, I would consider / try the following:

- Check which line(s) of code take the longest to run.  This can be done in a few seconds by putting in lines such as this:   `int point1 = Environment.TickCount;`  Subtracting subsequent points from each other will give you the time elapsed between the points in milliseconds.  Alternatively look into the `Stopwatch` class.  This information should narrow down where the problem is.
- Compare print performance from within WPF with performance from other applications.  Can a similarly complex MS Word document print more quickly?
- Check what data goes "over the wire" to the printer.  It's possible that the data being sent to the printer is much larger than you are expecting,  e.g. if it contains images that are not being scaled down at the source.

In general though, it would definitely help if you provided more information about your exact situation, e.g. are you printing over a network, or to USB printers?  How large is the document being printed, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned that I'm printing to a Datamax printer. However, that doesn't seem to be the issue since, again, I've narrowed it down to Win7. My question has been bumped up a couple of times, so I'm assuming that this is something that other WPF folks have come across too.

Comment: My one guess is that WPF documents produce slightly larger amounts of data that get streamed to the printer than usual, and that Datamax printers are probably not geared for that.  There also seem to be a large number of Win 7 printing slowness questions out there, such as [this one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/printing-is-very-very-slow-in-windows-7/477b5aba-a93d-4c5e-ac1f-329fed6459f3), no real answers though, but might get you on the right track, although I suspect you've already seen these.

Comment: It's eerie but I found this question & the answer under different names on another website: http://dotnethelpdesk.com/topics/4e49b45e3b530740a6000166 What's worse is that there is no credit whatsoever to SO if indeed they ripped off content from SO.

Comment: That's pretty messed up, thanks for bringing it up...  I doubt there's much that can be done about it however.  Is there any way to easily notify the mods in case they want to check it out?

Comment: Done that already. I emailed them as soon as I saw the site. For future reference, keep this email id in mind: team@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

The first thing which comes in my mind is to look if the printer driver under Windows 7 is slower.
Then i would blame WPF.
Try to use another printer or printer driver.